# Junit: How to Mock the HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, junit

How to mock the HttpURLConnection  to the getContent() method in the sample code , Also how to get the reponse from the mock url

```
public class WebClient {
   public String getContent(URL url) {
       StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
       try {

           HttpURLConnection connection = createHttpURLConnection(url);
           connection.setDoInput(true);
           InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
           int count;
           while (-1 != (count = is.read())) {
               content.append(new String(Character.toChars(count)));
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
       }
       return content.toString();
   }
   protected HttpURLConnection createHttpURLConnection(URL url) throws IOException{
       return (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

   } 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your `Webclient` is a bit badly designed for testing. You should avoid hidden dependencies (basically most `new` operations). To be mockable, these dependencies should be (preferably) given to the object under test in it's constructor or object under test should hold them in a field so they can be injected.

Alternatively you can extend your Webclient like

```
new Webclient() {
  @Override
  HttpURLConnection createHttpURLConnection(URL url) throws IOException{
    return getMockOfURLConnection();
}
```

where `getMockOfURLConnection` returns a mock of HttpURLConnection from mocking framework like Mockito. Then you you teach that mock to return what you want and use `verify` to check that it was correctly called.

Answer (score 2):

You should refactor your code : use the method [URL.openStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()) instead of this cast to `HttpURLConnection`. The code will be more simple, more generic amd easier to test.

```
public class WebClient {
    public String getContent(final URL url) {
        final StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            final InputStream is = url.openStream();
            int count;
            while (-1 != (count = is.read()))
                content.append(new String(Character.toChars(count)));
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

Then, you should mock the `URL`. This a final class so you can't mock it with Mockito. It remains several possibilities, in order of preference :

1. test with a fake resource in the classpath and use `WebClientTest.class.getResource("fakeResource")` to get an `URL`.
2. extract an interface `StreamProvider` allowing allowing to get the `InputStream` from an `URL` an inject in your `WebClient`.
3. use [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) for mocking the `final class URL`.

Comment: If I am not wrong, this solution works for GET requests only. For POST request I really need a HTTPUrlConnection object in order to set method and body.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use stubs for this , take a look at mockito.org it's an easy to use framework.  The idea is to mimick the behavior of the class and validate if your code handles the positive and negative scenarios.